# how to save the order of levels in a data frame?

Tags: r

I've just realized that when I use `write.table()` for saving a data frame in R it does not save the order in which I had set the levels of a particular factor variable.

Checking the levels of Species in iris:

```
> levels(iris$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Changing the order of the levels:

```
> iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, levels=c("virginica","setosa","versicolor"))
> levels(iris$Species)
[1] "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"
```

Saving the data frame and loading it into a new one:

```
> write.table(iris, 'iris_new.table')
> newIris <- read.table('iris_new.table')
```

Checking the order of new data frame:

```
> levels(newIris$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

How can I save the data frame so I can export it to other R sessions?

Comment: Try `save` or `saveRDS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use `save` and `load` instead.

```
save(iris,file = "Iris.RData")
```

will save the R object itself to a file, and then you load it back into your workspace using `load`. Don't be confused when `load` doesn't return an object. It loads it into your workspace, so if you type `ls()` you'll see it listed.

Comment: +1 For explaining how `load` works, I was indeed confused when I first used it.